# How to log in to remote website and read the data from logged in page using Javascript/Jquery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a website where I can read the data from remote website and show it on mine.

Remote websites I need to access all require username and password.
ex: http://wwww.boostmobile.com 
I have or will have correct login info in my database.

I would like to know how I can fill out the login info and submit it.
After successfully logging in I would like to read various data and send it back to my website.

I would like to this with Javascript, Jquery, or AJAX.

To sum it up these are my questions:

1. How to send login info to remote website and submit it?
2. How do you read and send back the data from logged in page to my website?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This is not possible in javascript. You need a server-side solution (php, python, etc)

Comment: It's possible in JavaScript, but only by using server-side javascript. If there's an API to the websites, then you can use AJAX requests in JavaScript but since you mention login forms, there's probably no API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is possible as stated by omouse. The following link may help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/