# Logging in and getting the data from the cross domain for calculations using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have already searched regarding this question and haven't found a satisfying answer.

May be this is somewhat related but doesn't have a satisfying answer.

[How to log in to remote website and read the data from logged in page using Javascript/Jquery/AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839557/how-to-log-in-to-remote-website-and-read-the-data-from-logged-in-page-using-java)

Firstly I want to develop a web app for my college academics website. You can see the website [here](https://academics.vit.ac.in/parent/parent_login.asp)

Now, I want to create a web app which takes in the Register Number, username and password (Date of Birth, phone number) as input and send this to the academics site and gets the data from the site and returns it back to my web app which will do some calculations and display the data. The webapp should only be written in javascript and its frameworks and of course html and css.
It should be noted that the data itself in the website of the academics gets its data in an iframe.

To be very brief, 
1) Go to the website
2) Get the capatcha
3) Go back to the website
4) Fill in all the username, passwords, captcha etc.
5) login
6) get the data
7) return the values for calculations.

I would appreciate if you would cite some code examples, tutorials.

Comment: okay then I will use php as my backend. If I will use PHP as my backend please suggest me a way. And one more thing I am not writing any API also that website doesn't have any API to use. @trex

Comment: sorry my understanding was incorrect while reading it last time. I'm not sure abt it.

Comment: No problem, please share the question if you think that if anyone knows the answer to my question.